# JPA merge of a OneToMany relation executing an INSERT statement in the jointable which leads to a ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I using Spring Data with JPA repositories. I have following entities:
A parent entity:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {

    @Id
    String id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    Set<Child> children;
}
```

Another parent:

```
@Entity
public class AnotherParent {
    @Id
    String id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    Set<Child> children;
```

}

and a child entity:

```
@Entity
public class Child {

    @Id
    String id;

    String value;
}
```

First i save a Parent with following structure for the first time, everything is correct:

```
{
    "id" : "1",
    "children" : [{
           id: "500", 
           value: "abc"
        }]
}
```

I have now a entry in my parents table `id:1`, child table `id:500, value:abc` and in a jointable (Parent_children) the relation `1 - 500`.
When i no try to save again the parent with id 1, with a changed value inside the child:

```
{
    "id" : "1",
    "children" : [{
           id: "500", 
           value: "def"
        }]
}
```

i can see that jpa executing an update-statment with `UPDATE children SET value='def' WHERE id=500` which is fine. But then it also tries to execute an insert statement for the jointable:
`INSERT INTO Parent_children (parent, child) VALUES (1, 500)` which of cause lead to a ConstraintViolationException because the entry already exists in the jointable. 
How can i prevent JPA to executing this insert statement?

Comment: Which method do you use to insert in database ? do you use `persiste methode or sevaOrUpdate Method ?` can you show some code where you save your data please ?

Comment: Post your controller. You should make a PUT request for the 2nd request to update.  Use POST only for a new record. Anyway, post your controller code.

Comment: You haven't shown us the entire code of the entites, either. Is there by any chance a custom `equals/hashCode` implementation in `Child`?